# Minimal cell structures

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Is there some reasonable obstruction theory which detects whether a finite type complex can be provided with a cell structure such that number of $i$-cells is equal to the maximal rank of $i$th homology among integral and $\Bbb Z/p$ coefficients?

Existence of nontrivial Massey products in "wrong" dimensions is, of course, a working one, but maybe there is something much easier that uses only integral/mod $p$ (co)homology just as a (co)ring without infinity structure or action of $\cal A_p$, or some information about fundamental group.

There is an old and well researched question: how one constructs weak Morse or Morse function with minimal number of critical points. But there ought to be some purely homotopical constraints, and I hope for something not very complicated.

Comment: Are you aware about the minimal structure theorem in Allen Hatcher's book? But this is only under the assumption that the space is simply connected and you obtain a homotopy equivalent cw complex with a minimal number of cells.

Comment: Yea, simply connected case is trivial by Hurewicz and usual obstruction theory, I'm mostly interested in the opposite case (when considered complex is a $K(G, 1)$)